# Que tipo de base de datos utilizar?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Si tengo una base de datos en **MySQL** con una tabla de usuarios, y quiero almacenar informacion inherente a cada usuario, como por ejemplo su imagen de perfil, historiales de conversacion, o simplemente imagenes o archivos que este usuario suba.

¿Que base de datos deberia usar para que los demas usuarios puedan acceder a esos datos?.

Con acceder me refiero a por ejemplo cuando ves que un usuario esta conectado ves su imagen de perfil o cuando te vas a su perfil puedes ver sin necesidad de descargar que archivos ha subido, he leido que MySQL no es lo mejor para estas tareas.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con descargar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar indicarte que lo que no debes hacer es almacenar los ficheros en la base de datos, lo que debes guardar son las referencias a estos, crea campos de tipo Varchar(XXX) e guarda el nombre del fichero que ha subido el usuario.

Por otra parte, MySQL es una base de datos muy apta para realizar lo que comentas, analiza los requerimientos que tienes, define las entidades y en base a estos define la/s tabla/s que necesitas para ello. Por lo poco que planteas ya necesitas dos tablas, una para los datos del usuario (en un campo guardaría el avatar) y otra para los documentos que los usuarios suben.

Luego es sólo cuestión de hacer las consultas para recuperar la información y cargar el listado de ficheros que ha subido sin necesidad de descargarlos.

Espero haberte aclarado las dudas.

Saludos!

Comment: Pero si guardo referencias estas a donde apuntan? A la maquina local de cada usuario? Si es asi cuando uno este desconectado los demas no pueden acceder a sus datos, o cargo los archivos en un ftp o algo parecido?

Comment: O cuando suba el archivo lo guardo en la maquina local del servidor y la referencia apunta hacia la memoria del servidor?

Comment: El fichero se guarda siempre en el mismo servidor donde ejecutas ti script.

Answer (score 1):

Te explico. En mi caso lo que haría es guardar lo assets en una carpeta por ejemplo:

```
/public/images/{{user_id}}/avatar.png
```

(esto en el servidor que le hace hosting a tu sitio) Entonces para mostrar la imagen de perfil de un user en tu site bastaría con poner

```
<img src="/public/images/{{user_id}}/avatar.png" />
```

Claro encargarte de guiar la lógica para que lo que esta entre {{ }} sea remplazado por información funcional.

Ahora eso con guardar los id de tus users en la BD es suficiente. Para las demás imágenes con crear una entidad "images" que tenga un atributo "ref" que haga referencia al nombre con que se guarda el archivo podrías guardarlos en:

```
/public/images/{{user_id}}/{{img_ref}}.{{date}}.jpeg
```

y crear una relación uno a muchos entre los "users" y las "imagenes" estarías listo ;)